# Momentjs two instances, different fromNow

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

what is the best practice in momentjs for creating a custom locale for fromNow() but also being able to use the standard one in other places?

I want to be able to use the normal fromNow ("a few days ago") but also a "short" fromNow ("1d+") ... meaning more than a day ago. I got it working, but now whenever I use fromNow() it always uses the "short" fromNow version

```
UI.registerHelper "momentizeFromNow", (ts) ->
  moment(ts).fromNow()

UI.registerHelper "momentizeFromNowShort", (ts) ->
  momentLocal = moment
  momentLocal.locale('en', relativeTime:
    future: "in %s"
    past:   "%s"
    s:  "now"
    m:  "1m"
    mm: "%dm+"
    h:  "1h"
    hh: "%dh+"
    d:  "1d"
    dd: "%dd+"
    w: "%dw"
    ww: "1w+"
    M:  "1w+"
    MM: "1w+"
    y:  "1w+"
    yy: "1w+"
  )
  momentLocal(ts).fromNow()
```

I have tried (unsuccessfully) using .clone() function

Comment: Sorry but what is `UI.registerHelper` ??

Comment: Sorry that is just a Meteor thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a custom locale and then either switch back and forth using `.locale()` or have two `moment()` variables.

Something like this:

```
moment.locale('en-cust', {
    relativeTime : {
    future: "in %s",
    past:   "%s",
    s:  "now",
    m:  "1m",
    mm: "%dm+",
    h:  "1h",
    hh: "%dh+",
    d:  "1d",
    dd: "%dd+",
    w: "%dw",
    ww: "1w+",
    M:  "1w+",
    MM: "1w+",
    y:  "1w+",
    yy: "1w+"
    }
});
//Defined custom locale as 'en-cust'

then = moment(1316116057189).locale('en');
thenCust = moment(1316116057189).locale('en-cust');
//Set variables to moments with specific locales

console.log(then.fromNow());
//4 years ago
console.log(thenCust.fromNow());
//1w+
console.log(thenCust.locale('en').fromNow());
//4 years ago -> switched locale with chaining method
console.log(then.locale('en-cust').fromNow());
//1w+ -> switched locale with chaining method
console.log(then.fromNow());
//1w+ as it is still set for 'en-cust' from previous chain
then.locale('en');
//Set it back
console.log(then.fromNow());
//4 years ago
```

Comment: hmm I would think this would work but it may be an issue with meteor binding to moment and switching globally when locale is changed. Is there any way to extend moment to create a new function (fromNowShort())?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Meteor, but it shouldn't break any of the chains I mentioned. Have you tested the `yourMoment.locale('en-cust').fromNow()` chain, switching the `locale()`as needed?